# openSUSE 15.4 zypper error installing postgreSQL

Tags: linux, postgresql, opensuse

I am new to Linux,
I installed openSUSE Leap 15.4, and made the root directory ext4, I then followed these steps to install postgreSQL 13 on my system

1.`sudo zypper ref && sudo zypper update`

2. sudo zypper addrepo https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/zypp/repo/pgdg-sles-15-pg13.repo

But after this, I `sudo zypper ref` again and it shows an error saying:

```
Retrieving repository 'PostgreSQL 13 SLES 15.4 - x86_64' metadata .....................................[error]
Repository 'PostgreSQL 13 SLES 15.4 - x86_64' is invalid.
[pgdg-13|https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/zypp/13/suse/sles-15.4-x86_64] Valid metadata not found at specified URL
History:
 - [pgdg-13|https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/zypp/13/suse/sles-15.4-x86_64] Repository type can't be determined.
```

what can I do to install postgreSQL

Comment: If all fails, build it from source. That's not difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say precisely why your zypper command failed, but it might have to do with the fact that the repositories from your link are intended for SUSE Linux Enterprise 15 SP4, not for openSUSE Leap 15.4, which is what you're using. So even if you did get these repositories to work, you might run into other compatibility problems later.

To install postgresql, there is always the option to search for your package on [software.opensuse.org](https://software.opensuse.org). (I strongly recommend you bookmark this page – it's *the* place to look for openSUSE packages.) For postgresql13, there is indeed an official *experimental* package available for openSUSE 15.4, namely [here](https://software.opensuse.org/package/postgresql13), which you can install via 1-Click-Install. However, the newer version postgresql14 is already out for quite a while, so I would only advise for using the older postgresql13 if you have a very strong reason to do so. The newer postgresql14 also has an official experimental package available for openSUSE 15.4, namely [here](https://software.opensuse.org/package/postgresql14); this is the one I would recommend currently.

Answer (score 0):

first check if repo is enabled `zypper repos -d`

check `/etc/zypp/repos.d/pgdg-13.repo` file

Answer (score 0):

If you open the added repo file all set `sles`. but i think the main problem is the `type=rpm-md`. In any case you dont need add third part repo to install postgress. the package is already in the main repos and is called `postgresql-server`.

So remove the `https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/zypp/repo/pgdg-sles-15-pg13.repo` to prevent any other issues and package conflicts

```
zypper lr # to list the repos and find the number for the `https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/zypp/repo/pgdg-sles-15-pg13.repo`
zypper rr <number>
```

Then just install `postgresql-server`

Btw when you refresh the packages you dont need to run `update`